# How can I load user control thru cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I have two user controls created in my UC folder. I need to load them in my page depending on the scenario based in the CS file. In my CS file I have

```
    protected override string GetMessage()
    {

        if (previousAttempts == 0)  
        {
            message = GetResourceString("Intro");
        }
        else if (previousAttempts == 1)  
        {
            message = GetResourceString("Intro2");

    //LOAD USER CONTROL ONE HERE

        }
        else  
        {
            message = GetResourceString("Pass");


    //LOAD USER CONTROL TWO HERE



        }

        return message;
    }
```

I have my user controls registered in the default page as follows

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/AnswerUC1.ascx" TagPrefix="UC1" TagName="ANSWERUC1" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/AnswerUC2.ascx" TagPrefix="UC2" TagName="AnswerUC2" %>
```

How Can i call this and make it load thru my CS file?

Comment: from the .cs, LoadControl()

Comment: Look here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302130/loading-user-controls-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are going to load this into a place holder control (placeHolder1),

```
placeHolder1.Controls.Add((ANSWERUC1)LoadControl("~/UserControls/AnswerUC1.ascx"));
```

There is an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that explains this in detail with samples.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this controls in your .aspx file. Your control have to run as Server! and give them unique id. Now, you can access them in your code-behind through these unique ids!